# Android appstore

Tags: android

Just a quick question, On Android there are various appstore's. For instance Google's own, Amazon's etc.

Is it possible for other 3rd parties to easily create there own app store?

Answer (score 1):

If a device supports side-loading of apps, yes. In fact, you can download and prompt the user to install applications from any other application. Just trigger the phone to download the corresponding APK. The difficult part is getting developers to pay and submit their apps to you.

Comment: So would the phone need to be rooted?

Comment: Nope. The phone just needs to have the option to "Allow installation of non-Market applications" in the Applications screen of the device's settings. That's what allows you to install external apps. Some phones don't ship with the ability to turn this on, and in those cases, yes, the phone needs to be rooted to allow this to be turned on.